# TinyMCE: How to post use key combination Shift Enter?

Tags: post, tinymce, shift, enter, onkeypress

I'm using the TinyMCE editor in chat and very uncomfortable to send a message by submit-button. 
I would like to know, how post message use "onkeypress" in TinyMCE ?

I do this so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
...
        setup : function(ed) {
            ed.onKeyPress.add(
                function (ed, evt) {
                    if(evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode == 13) {
                        AjaxPost();
                        //alert('shift + enter key');
                        return;
            }              
        });
    }
...
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function PostAjax()
{
var Message=document.getElementById('Message').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PostTinyMCE.php?Message="+Message,
        success: function(html)
        {
        $("#General").html(html);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<textarea name="content" id="Message" style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

but it does not give me the desired effect, functions AjaxPost(); does't start, where is my mistake?
Please help me...

Comment: try to place your js function before the tinymce init

Answer (score 0):

Use an alert statement in function `AjaxPost` to check if the function `AjaxPost();` gets executed. If no, try to place your js function before the tinymce init. If yes you need to verify your ajax code.